# Why coffeescript doesn't work when the page jump to a new one in ROR

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

my xxx.js.coffee 's contents:

```
$->
  $("#clk").click ->
    alert "hello world"

  $("#clk1").click ->
    alert "hello"
```

the id "clk" is in the index.html.erb and the "clk1" is in the show.html.erb

when i in "index.html.erb", the coffee works, but when i jump to the "show.html.erb", it doesn't alert any thing.

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery in Rails is failing after linking from another page, works on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623248/jquery-in-rails-is-failing-after-linking-from-another-page-works-on-page-load) or at least the answer is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `$ ->`, you probably already know that you're telling jQuery to run the function on `DOMContentLoaded` or a similar event. Unfortunately, the later versions of Rails have a feature called turbolinks turned on by default. This features speeds up your pages by telling the browser not to reload the page when you click on a new link, and instead to just fetch the new page via ajax and replace the current body with it.

The downside is that the page is not reloaded and your '#clk1' handler registration will not run again when `show.html.erb` is displayed. As mu already pointed out in the comments, check out the answer to this question for the correct event to use:

[JQuery in Rails is failing after linking from another page, works on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623248/jquery-in-rails-is-failing-after-linking-from-another-page-works-on-page-load)

Personally, the first thing I do on any new Rails 4 project is remove turbolinks. I think it causes more problems than it solves. Just remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your `Gemfile`.

Comment: On a side note, this has absolutely nothing to do with CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's very useful~ ^-^

Comment: Excellent thanks, been hitting my head against a wall for a couple of hours on this