# jQuery not executing when navigating within rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have jQuery/Coffeescript in a rails app that runs successfully when first navigating to the root_path and/or reloading the page, however, if I navigate to another page using a link on the home page, and then navigate back to the home page, the jQuery (which should run when the page finishes loading) does not run. Why is this? How can I make it so that it runs every time the page is hit? Thanks!

**'/home.js.coffee'**

```
jQuery ->
  myFunction ->

$('#my_div').click myFunction
```

*Note:* I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks    <- including this line gives me an error "Sprockets::FileNotFound"
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: How are you hooking into the page load event? Can you post the jquery code

Comment: Added some code to show how I use the function

Comment: So, the problem is that 'click' does not get bound the next time you hit the home page?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that would make sense. I think it's related to Turbolinks, but when I added https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks into my application.js (and my gemfile), I kept getting an error saying "Sprockets::FileNotFound". I'll add my application.js file above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery in Rails is failing after linking from another page, works on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623248/jquery-in-rails-is-failing-after-linking-from-another-page-works-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your coffeescript file:

```
myFunction = ->
  # this is what the function does.

$ -> # this gets called when the DOM is ready (thanks to jquery.turbolinks gem)
  $('#my_div').click myFunction
```